# Is there a way to read in a large document as a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I'm trying to use ggplot2 on a large data set stored into a `csv` file. I used to read it with excel.

I don't know how to convert this data into a `data.frame`. In particular, I have a date column that has the following format: *"2020/04/12:12:00"*. How can I get `R` to understand this format ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a `csv`, you can use:

- `fread` function from `data.table`. This will be the fastest way to read your csv.
- `read_csv` or `read_csv2` (for `;` delimited documents) in `readr` package

If it's `.xls` (or `.xlsx`) document, have a look at the `readxl` package.

All these functions import your data as `data.frame`s (with additional classes like `data.table` for `fread` or `tibble` for `read_csv`).

## Edit

Given your comment, it looks like your file is not an excel but a csv. If you want to convert a column type to date, assuming your dataframe is called `df`

```r
df[, dates := as.POSIXct(get(colnames(df)[1]), format = "%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M")]
```

Note that you don't need to use `cbind` or even reassign the `data.table` because you use `:=` operator

As the message is saying you, you don't need the extra-precision of `POSIXlt`

Comment: I think fread did load it in - but before I can plot I need to change the date column to Rdates so that R can read it - this was fine when reading in normally and using : Rdates<-strptime(data[,1],format="%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M")
    then:   cbind(data,Rdates)  but when trying to bind the the fread readd-in file i got this message :   "Warning message:
In as.data.table.list(x, keep.rownames = keep.rownames, check.names = check.names,  :
  POSIXlt column type detected and converted to POSIXct. We do not recommend use of POSIXlt at all because it uses 40 bytes to store one date. "

Comment: I proposed you a solution to this problem, based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511617/how-to-convert-an-ambiguous-datetime-column-in-data-table-without-using-strptime). You don't need to `cbind` vectors, you `data.table` you can directly modify the dataframe by creating/deleting new columns

Comment: Nice, however when I got to plot with the data now (after the date setting code) like so... "ggplot(data="df", aes(x="Date/time (yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mm)", y="y column", group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()"  ...   I get this warning: "Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a character vector"

Comment: That's normal, you have several errors in this syntax. You should use `ggplot(data=df, aes(x = x_var, y=y_var)) +  geom_line()+ geom_point()`. Change `x_var` and `y_var` to the names of your variables (without quotes)

Comment: Hm, still getting errors (unexpected symbol and fortify errors) - ... RiverWensum<-fread("River Wensum Water Quality 2013-14 (1).csv")
#to get rdates#
RiverWensum[, dates := as.Date(get(colnames(RiverWensum)[1]), format = "%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M")]
#to plot#ggplot(data=RiverWensum, aes(x = Date/time (yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mm), y=Nitrate (mg N L))) + geom_line()+ geom_point()

Comment: I think you should read some doc about [ggplot](https://bookdown.org/agrogankaylor/quick-intro-to-ggplot2/quick-intro-to-ggplot2.html). `aes` is not the place for labels but variables. `ggplot(data=RiverWensum, aes(x = dates, y = nitrate)) + geom_line()+ geom_point()` might work assuming your `y` variable is named `nitrate`. If you want to discover `ggplot` you can have a look at the [esquisse](https://github.com/dreamRs/esquisse) package

Comment: the esquisse package was helpful, thanks - a question though :when I open my data and plot in esquisse::esquisser () I can coerce th data. How do I keep this coersion in R? Data seems to go back to normal as soon as the esquisse:esquisser tab is closed

Comment: Never used `esquisse` myself, only heard about it so I cannot help on that point

Answer (score 0):

Going by the question alone, I would suggest the openxlsx package, it has helped me reduce the time significantly in reading large datasets. Three points you may find it to be helpful based on your question and the comments

- The read command stays same as xlsx package, however would suggest you to use **openxlsx::read.xslx(file_path)**
- the arguments are again same, but in the place of **sheetIndex** it is **sheet** and it takes only numbers
- If the existing columns are converted to character, then a simple **as.Date** would work

Comment: Ah okay but when i go to plot i still get an error code "Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a character vector"
    ...    "RiverWensum<-fread("River Wensum Water Quality 2013-14 (1).csv")
head(RiverWensum)
#to get rdates
RiverWensum[, dates := as.Date(get(colnames(RiverWensum)[1]), format = "%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M")]

ggplot(data="RiverWensum", aes(x="Date/time (yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mm)", y="Nitrate (mg N/L)", group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()"